# Eclipse plugin to get the count of word being searched in the console

Tags: eclipse

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that could display the get count of word being searched in the [Eclipse console](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fconsole%2Fref-console_view.htm).  (i.e., the number of occurrences of a particular string in the console.)

I could copy the entire console into some Notepad++ window, and then use the Ctrl+F search, but that's inconvenient:

[image]

Comment: You mean the number of occurrences of a particular string, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul yes